# Merge Duplicate Columns In A pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I will appreciate your assistance. I have a pandas DataFrame that has duplicate columns I need to merge/combine the contents to be under unique columns please see below my current DataFrame Structure and the desired one.

**Current DF**

| **AB** | **XY** | **AB** | **XY** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yyy | xxx | xrx | zzz |

**Desired DF**

| **AB** | **XY** |
| --- | --- |
| yyy | xxx |
| xrx | zzz |

Thanks for the help

Comment: you have a duplicate column in pandas or elsewhere? can you do `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: yes the referred question answers my question